# BLE cannot scan after cloning Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: bluetooth, raspberry-pi-os, cron, raspberry-pi-os-buster

I have **raspberry-pi 2** and i made a python program. My python program can detect BLE and send scan results using MQTT. The program will run automatically when restarted [Using cron-table]. Then I did mass cloning using the OS developed on Raspberry-pi2. After cloning, I tried on **raspberry-pi 3** but ***BLE can't be scanned***.

I've tried to troubleshoot by:

1. Turn off crontab and run python program with terminal **[BLE scan success]**
2. Run crontab again after doing hciconfig up and hciconfig down. **[Not successful]**
3. Added shell script before python program in crontab **[Unsuccessful]**
4. Run the command "sudo hcitool lescan" **[scan success]**

An indication of the problem that occurs is that when the cron-table is turned on, the BLE scan cannot run.

List of Figures:

1. When running the program in terminal ["sudo python3 scanning.py"]
   [image]
2. When running the command "sudo hcitool lescan" in the terminal
   [image]
3. Command on crontable
   [image]

Hardware:

1. Raspberry Pi 2 Model B V1.2
2. Raspberry Pi 3 Model B+

Operating System:

1. OS 10 [2021-03-04-raspios-buster-armhf-full.img]

**Can anyone help? What caused this to happen?**

Comment: How are you doing the scanning in your Python code? `hciconfig` has been [deprecated](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/commit/?id=b1eb2c4cd057624312e0412f6c4be000f7fc3617) . What is the status reported when you do `sudo service bluetooth status`? Are there any errors reported in `journalctl -k`? There are some benefits to using [systemd](https://blog.usedbytes.com/2019/11/run-at-startup-without-rc.local/) for startup scripts like making sure the required parts of the system are up before running your script. In crontab, you can put a long sleep before your script is started?

Comment: Also, it is preferred if you copy and paste text (and format in a code block) rather than put screenshots

Comment: @ukBaz I'm sorry, the program code is secret. But, I describe correctly and I'm sure it's not coded wrong because this system has been running for almost 2 years on raspberry-pi 2.

Comment: @ukBaz oh thanks, i have a error like this "Sap driver initialization failed." and "Failed to set privacy: Rejected (0x0b)"

Comment: Are you running any of the cloned systems close to the original? If so turn all of the cloned ones off, and just use the original.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's a stupid solution, just make delay after rebooting system if you used crontable

```
@reboot sleep 15 && /home/pi/Desktop/..... .py
```

I'm sorry because my brain is stopped working. :D Have a nice day